# Problem with unexisting new replies

Tags: support, site-general

I've noticed a problem with the "You have new replies" button. The last 3 times I've seen the yellow envelope, I've clicked on it but actually there were no replies at all.

Did anyone experienced the same behaviour? Any clue?

Comment: I have experienced this many, many times.  It seems that the envelope has many problems, or at least it had many problems at some point of time.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=envelope

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: One thing that often happens is that if I have favorite changes or other such things, the envelope lights up. even if I have no new replies

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68387/the-envelope-icon-driving-me-mad-with-false-positives, but keep in mind that many things changed recently about the behavior of the envelope icon.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I've thought I had no replies, I realized I just needed to click the "show n more comments" link to actually see the replies. It's not at all obvious that I needed to do so, so for a long time I thought it was misreporting comments.